# ui-router set params from resolve

Tags: angular-ui-router

Hi I wondering is it possible set param in ui-router data which from resolve. This example doesen't work, what's wrong ?

```
            resolve : {
            userItem : [function () {
                return "name";

            }]
        },
        params: {
            title: $resolve.userItem ,

        },
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
//...
    resolve: {
        userItem: function($stateParams){
            $stateParams.title = "whatever";
            return {data: "whatever"};
        }
    },
    params:{
        title:null  
    }
//...
```

Comment: Don't work, I think params{titile : null} override  $stateParams.title = "whatever";

Comment: Yes, it overrides, but, once resolver gets resolved, it should put the value into the param. Also, can you please share your results, does it gives any console errors?

Comment: Any console errors, I made $timeout in resolve to  $stateParams.title = "whatever", but end effect in component is null

Comment: What actually you want to achieve?

Comment: I want my  $stateParams.title set by data from resolve and then I will be able to use in other place in application

Comment: You do not need to use params to achieve that, you can use your resolve object in your controllers. Just inject it into the controller as any other dependency.

Comment: @mbeso But you can use it - you will need to inject $state, where you want to use it, and then access the data as this: $state.params.title.

Comment: This is not working. Changes done to $stateParams are not reflected to actual state